# Longitud de matriz en Go

Tags: go

Estoy empezando con Go (o Golang), y quería saber cómo obtener el tamaño de una matriz, por ejemplo de tipo `[][]uint8`.

Intenté usando `len`, pero me da error.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 6):

En Go todos los arreglos que se crean tienen una longitud definida y esta hace parte de su tipo:

```
var array [10]uint8
var arrayOfArrays [7][3]uint8
```

En el primer caso, la variable `array` es un arreglo de 10 elementos de tipo `uint8` y en el segundo la variable `arrayOfArrays` es un arreglo de 7 elementos donde cada elemento es un arreglo de 3 elementos de tipo `uint8`. Esa declaración es equivalente a:

```
var arrayOfArrays [7]([3]uint8)
```

Ahora, Go tiene una función incorporada llamada `len()` que devuelve un número entero equivalente a la longitud del objeto que se le pase como parámetro, si el objeto es un arreglo devuelve el número de elementos en ese arreglo. Eso quiere decir que:

```
len(array)
```

retorna el número de elementos del arreglo `array` (10). Para el arreglo de arreglos `arrayOfArrays` (o la 'matriz', como lo llamas):

```
var filas = len(arrayOfArrays)
```

retornará 7, porque esta variable es un arreglo de **7** elementos, donde cada elementos es también otro arreglo, y

```
var columnas = len(arrayOfArrays[0])
```

retornará 3, en este caso el valor devuelto es el número de elementos del primer arreglo que es en sí un elemento del arreglo `arraysOfArrays`. Si el objetivo es saber cuántos elementos tiene en total el arreglo de arreglos el valor es la multiplicación de las variables filas y columnas. A diferencia de otros lenguajes, en Go no es posible crear un arreglo de elementos que sean arreglos de diferentes tamaños, por lo que se tiene la seguridad que el número de elementos [la longitud] de un arreglo de arreglos es la multiplicación del número de filas y columnas.

Comment: Ahora el error que tengo es al pasarlo a una función:

Comment: Ahora el error que tengo es al pasarlo a una función: unc ejemplp(matriz [][]uint8)

Comment: @Aaron, recuerda que al pasar argumentos a una función, en la gran mayoría de casos, sólo pasas el nombre de la variable, como `ejemplo(matriz)`

Answer (score 0):

`var a [5][3]int;`// declaracion de la matriz

`len(a);` //tamano de las columnas de la matriz

`len(a[0]);` //tamano de las filas de la matriz

Answer (score 0):

Existe una diferencia entre el tipo `[7][3]uint8` y `[][]uint8`, la diferencia es que el primero es un **array** mientras que el segundo es un **slice**, puedes leer mas aqui: [Documentacion oficial](https://golang.org/blog/go-slices-usage-and-internals). El primero no puede cambiar su tamanno por lo cual no es muy util preguntar su `len`, pues ya se sabe es 7 filas y 3 columnas. El uso de `len()` gana utilidad cuando el tipo es un slice `[][]uint8`, pues no sabemos cuantos elementos pueden haber.

El siguiente codigo me funciona perfectamente, no tengo claro cual puede ser el error que tienes.

```golang
func main() {
    var a [][]uint8
    var b []uint8

    println(len(a))

    a = append(a,b)
    println(len(a))
    println(len(a[0]))
}
```

No se puede preguntar `len(a[0])` antes de agregar un nuevo elemento, como se hace en `a = append(a,b)`, esto se debe a que los slice son una referencia a lo que en realidad es un array en memmoria, entonces 'a[0] no existe previo a `a = append(a,b)`

En este caso la salida seria:

```
0
1
0
```